# Why is the network layer considered to be connectionless?

Tags: osi

Why is the network layer in the OSI model considered to be connectionless when you have Virtual Circuits that are a part of the layer and is connection oriented?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there is no "state " in the network layer nor signaling for connection setup.  Packets are forwarded based on destination address and each packet is forwarded irrespective of previous traffic.